# What are the strengths of chalk paint?

Tags: paint

Last summer I made a pallet style table for a friend. I made my own custom chalk paint using drywall compound and one litre of white latex paint. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.homehardware.ca/en/index/home-experts/bev-bell/all-projects/fall-projects/chalk-it-up.htm):

> Mix 1/4 cup to 1/2 cup drywall compound into the paint. The amount of drywall compound depends on how thick you want the paint. **Do not exceed 1/2 cup**. The first coat is normally straight paint with no drywall compound added.

I put emphasis on the portion that I paid attention to. I didn't add too much as I figured it would be too thick or clumpy so it would not apply well. I stirred it well enough that the drywall compound was mixed into the paint.

[image]

I thought the end result would be textured but it painted fairly flat. I then distressed it and it did turn out well but I feel the effort in making the paint didn't yield any results.

What is it about chalk paint that makes it popular? Is there something I might have done wrong with my paint mixture that cause less than ideal results?

Answer (score 6):

My experience is with the commercial brands (my wife uses and sells them).  The two main advantages that I see are:

- that they allow a very smooth finish with a brush.  If you were to paint furniture with latex paint, you'd get a lot more brush strokes than with chalk paint.
- it's easy to do the shabby chic thing (distressing, ageing, etc) with chalk paint.

Disadvantages:

- It's damned expensive, compared to regular latex paint.
- You can't color match like you can with regular paint (where the paint guy scans a color sample and the computer matches it)
- It's not a durable surface at all. For furniture and such it has to be sealed or waxed, which is another step.

Comment: Adding the disadvantages here is very helpful, especially the need for sealing/waxing. Welcome to [crafts.se] and thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

The whole appeal of Chalk Paint is the matte/flat result achieved on a variety of surfaces, requiring little to no prep, fast dry time, opacity control & finishing options.

To achieve a textured surface, additional products/tools, techniques and/or a different recipe is needed. The better quality of latex paint & type of finish (flat is recommended), produces slightly different & better results.

I'm not sure why you chose that particular recipe. Or why the first step says to paint the first layer w/o any drywall compound mixed in... The 3 well tested, popular recipes, use different ingredients, have flexible mix measurements, and instruct to apply directly to the object. I always do TONS of research beforehand when it comes to diy.

Pros:

- Minimal to no prep required
- Ability to adhere to a variety of surfaces
- Finishing options
- Muted colors
- Matte/Flat finish
- Quick dry time
- Variety of Chalk Paint Brands, now available in store.

Cons:

- Finishing work
- Cost
- Trend (resulting in large quantities of ruined pieces)